# Which ANSI code should I use to make text muted (dark gray)?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, command-line-interface

When I use code `1;30m` it produces different results:

```
Xshell 5: gray and bold 
PhpStorm terminal: only bold 
Windows console: only gray
```

The goal is to make a part of text to be slightly muted, but if it possible, it should display similarly in most terminal clients.

Anyway I don't understand how "bold" flag can change the foreground color. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ANSI didn't specify that.  ANSI listed *black*, *red*, etc., and also mentions *bold*.  How a particular terminal displays bold+black is implementation-defined (no standard applies).

"ANSI" refers to x3.64, withdrawn many years ago, replaced by ECMA-48 (aka ISO 6429).

For your amusement:

- [ECMA-48:
  Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)
- [Aren't bright colors the same as bold?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bold_vs_16colors) (xterm FAQ)
- [How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color) (ncurses FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, on xterm that displays a muted gray and on emacs it produces black.

You can try a 256-color code like `^[[38;2;85;85;85m` (which may also give inconsistent results for the reasons mentioned in @ThomasDickey's linked articles).